# R rename duplicate col and rownames (subindexing)

Tags: r, matrix

I would very much appreciate if a kind soul could tell me how to do this in R:

Given a squared matrix with duplicated columns and rows, such as

```
       1     1     2     2     2     2     3
1  0.000 0.000 0.048 0.048 0.048 0.048 0.059
1  0.000 0.000 0.048 0.048 0.048 0.048 0.059
2  0.048 0.048 0.000 0.000 0.000 0.000 0.059
2  0.048 0.048 0.000 0.000 0.000 0.000 0.059
2  0.048 0.048 0.000 0.000 0.000 0.000 0.059
2  0.048 0.048 0.000 0.000 0.000 0.000 0.059
3  0.059 0.059 0.059 0.059 0.059 0.059 0.000
```

where same col and row names designate duplicates, I require to have unique col and row names, while keeping track of original and duplicate cols/rows. That is, something like

```
        1    1a     2    2a    2b    2c     3
1   0.000 0.000 0.048 0.048 0.048 0.048 0.059
1a  0.000 0.000 0.048 0.048 0.048 0.048 0.059
2   0.048 0.048 0.000 0.000 0.000 0.000 0.059
2a  0.048 0.048 0.000 0.000 0.000 0.000 0.059
2b  0.048 0.048 0.000 0.000 0.000 0.000 0.059
2c  0.048 0.048 0.000 0.000 0.000 0.000 0.059
3   0.059 0.059 0.059 0.059 0.059 0.059 0.000
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You could use `?make.unique` or `?make.names`:

```
v <- as.character(c(1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3))
make.unique(v)
# [1] "1"   "1.1" "2"   "2.1" "2.2" "2.3" "3"
```

(You have to combine this with `rownames` and `colnames`.)